# .htaccess rewriterule with ssl

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^i/(.+)$ indexa.php?variable=$1
```

I am redirection url like this http://www.sitename.com/i/pages.html

with this redirection I am writing everything after i/ to a variable. There is no any problem. ( i/ folder does not exist on server).

But I installed SSL on my server and now I recive Error 404 that file is not finded on the server. I am googling for a day and stil did not find answer.

Also this is my 000-default.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /root/example.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/example.key
 SSLCACertificateFile /root/ssl-bundle.crt
 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR]/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
<Directory /var/www>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^i/(.+)$ indexa.php?variable=$1
</Directory>
```

into my 000-default.conf file and after that run follow command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

now everything is working. if I face with any other problem I will update my question and answer.